# Weird flot behaviour in AJAX calls

Tags: javascript, ajax, flot

I'm getting some really weird behaviour when adding flot plots through AJAX.

This is the result:
[image]

It always only displays the last graph. This can easily be confirmed due to the fact that the calls are asynchronous, and as such the order of the plots is random - the data being fed into flot is not the issue.

My current code for the AJAX call:

```
function addGraph(x, y, z){
  $.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    method: "GET",
    url: "/api.php",
    data: { a: "b", c:$("#d").val(), e: z}
  }).done(function( plotdata ){
    $("#graph").html($("#graph").html() + y.format(x));
    $.plot($("#plot-"+x), plotdata.data, plotdata.options);
  });
}
```

The `y` variable is a string that's formatted through a `sprintf` like function and looks like this:

```
<div class="col-md-6" style="height:250px;" id="plot-{0}"></div>
```

Comment: `$("#graph").html($("#graph").html() + y.format(x));` I think this will overwrite previous graphs, as you use `.html()`, but can't be sure as you didn't provide markups for further inspection.

Comment: @fuyushimoya You are indeed completely right, changing `$().html()` to `$().append()` fixed the issue. I didn't expect taking the plot out and putting it back would break the functionality. Thanks!